# Output multiple array php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

i have this code

```
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){  
   $array = array(
       'NAME' => 'name'.$i,
       'NUMBER' => 'peserta'.$i,
   );
}
```

i wanna get output like this

```
[
 "NAME" => name1,     
 "NUMBER" => number1,
],
[
 "NAME" => name2,     
 "NUMBER" => number2,
]
```

what should I return / do ?

Comment: $array['data'][] = array( ... ?

Comment: like that i have edit the post. i hope you get my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this:

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
   $filepath = public_path('template.rtf');    
   $array[] = array(
       'NAME' => 'name'.$i,
       'NUMBER' => 'peserta'.$i,
   );
}

print_r($array); // or var_dump($array)
```

Comment: @MuhammadZainulMutaqin yes, return $array

Comment: i've tried but output was empty, am I wrong ? check https://3v4l.org/dDGiL

Comment: @MuhammadZainulMutaqin oh, got it, I edited my answer. you must use print_r or var_dump to see your array

Comment: This would actually output name0 and peserta0 in the first iteration.

Comment: yes @bestprogrammerintheworld. so how to output both of the iteration?

Comment: @MikeFoxtech why i can't use echo or return ? cause I use dd (debugging) on laravel it just show the first iteration.

Comment: @MuhammadZainulMutaqin echo is not used for arrays. And return is only used in functions or methods. Please provide more information to help you

Comment: @MuhammadZainulMutaqin Change $i to ($i+1) or $i to $i+1.

Answer (score 2):

you can not display multiple arrays in one key
but you can add them to one array , like this.

you should instead of:

```
$array = ...
```

use:

```
$array[] = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output each item and echo an array each time you could do this:

```
<?php
foreach(range(1,2) as $i) {  
    $array = array(
        'NAME' => 'name'.$i,
        'NUMBER' => 'peserta'.$i,
    );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';
 }
```

If you want to create an array:

```
foreach(range(1,2) as $i) {  
    $array[] = array(
        'NAME' => 'name'.$i,
        'NUMBER' => 'peserta'.$i,
    );
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```